# Ionic Storage Issue for less memory space

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-storage

I am using ionic storage in my app and It needs almost 1GB device space to launch the app.
If device memory is not having at least 1GB of space app will not be launched. After clearing that memory I am able to launch.

this the way, I am trying to save some data after signing-in into local storage.

```
const seq = this.api.post('signin', value).share();
    seq.subscribe((res: any) => {
      // If the API returned a successful response, mark the user as logged in
      if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        (window as any).FirebasePlugin.setUserProperty('loggedInUserId', res.user);
        this.passwordMismatch = '';
        this.invalidSinIn = false;
        const isExistingUser = true;
        // store details into ionic storage
        Promise.all([this.storage.set('user', res.user), this.storage.set('token', res.token),
        this.storage.set('isVerified', res.isVerified), this.storage.set('authType', 'email'),
        this.storage.set('refreshToken', res.refreshToken), this.storage.set('referalCode', res.referalCode),
        this.storage.set('existingUser', isExistingUser), this.storage.set('isProfileCompleted', res.isProfileCompleted)]).then(() => {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(MainPage);
        });
      }
    });
```

This is working fine if the device is having available space of More then 1GB, but failing if memory is less.

Please help me to solve this issue. I am new in ionic
I am using

ionic framework: 3.9.2

Ionic App scripts: 3.1.2

Angular Core: 5.0.0

Comment: what are you trying to save, which needs this much memory space?

Comment: I have specified in the code, please have a look, Mostly I am saving some boolean values and JWT-token

Comment: The above-given code does not indicate any hint about your problem. There is something else, which is causing the problem. My suggestion would be to put your code on git or somewhere else and share the code.